# AVR keyboard COM-08653 issue

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, avr-gcc, atmega

I am trying to figure out how to read input from my COM-08653 keyboard with Atmega 32. View of the circuit and some arduino tutorials gave me a brief view about how this should look. 
Unfortunately, I get no input and I have no idea why.

```
char test()
{
    char result = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)    
    {
        PORTD |= (1 << colPinMap[col]);
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row ++)   
        {
            int pattern = 1 << rowPinMap[row];
            if((PIND & 0b1111) == pattern)
            {
                char debounce = 0;
                for(int db = 0; db < 10; db++)
                {
                    _delay_ms(1);
                    if((PIND & 0b1111) != pattern)
                    {
                        debounce = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!debounce)
                {
                    PORTA = 1 << 3;     //testing if the press is beeing noticed
                    while((PIND & 0b1111) == pattern) ;
                    PORTA = 0b0000;
                    result = keymap[row][col];
                }
            }
        }
        PORTD &= ~(1 << colPinMap[col]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've tried many times using a little bit different code, but it does not work. 
I've checked this keyboard, it works, I have also checked if the columns and rows are connected properly. Unfortunately I am sure of that.

This is ports configuration:

```
#define COLS 3
#define ROWS 4
char keymap[COLS][ROWS] = 
{
    { '1', '2', '3' },
    { '4', '5', '6' },
    { '7', '8', '9' },
    { '*', '0', '#' }
};
int colPinMap[COLS] = { 4, 5, 6 };
int rowPinMap[ROWS] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
keyConfig()
{
    DDRD = 0xf0;
    PORTD = 0x0f;
    //PORTD = 0x00;
    DDRA = 0xff;
    _delay_ms(2000);
}
```

Nothing happens and I have no idea why. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If this might be of any use to anyone, I have solved the problem. 
Port D (lower nibble) was set as input, and than pulled up. As input pins were pulled up, I was reading their states wrong. To find the key that has been pressed, the LOW state needs to be find, and I was trying to find HIGH state.
The solution looks something like this:
Set Column handling outputs to HIGH state,
For ecery column: 
Set current column output state to LOW,
Then find row input having LOW state.

As I have not found many descriptions of COM-08653 usage with AVR (most of the examples on the Internet are made for arduino), I provide You with an example:

```
#define COLS 3
#define ROWS 4
char keymap[ROWS][COLS] = 
{
    { '1', '2', '3' },
    { '4', '5', '6' },
    { '7', '8', '9' },
    { '*', '0', '#' }
};
int colPinMap[COLS] = { 4, 5, 6 };
int rowPinMap[ROWS] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };


void keyConfig()
{
    DDRA = 0xff;
    DDRC = 0xf0;        //0 - 3 => input / 4 - 7 => output
    PORTC = 0x0f;       // output => LOW / input => PULL UP
}

char readKey()
{
    char result = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
    {
        PORTC = 0xff ^(1 << colPinMap[col]);
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            if ((PINC & 0b1111) == (0b1111 ^ (1 << row)))
            {
                char isBouncing = 0;
                for (int db = 0; db < 5; db++)
                {
                    if((PINC & 0b1111) != (0b1111 ^ (1 << row)))
                    {
                        isBouncing = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(!isBouncing)
                    {
                        while((PINC & 0b1111) == (0b1111 ^ (1 << row))) ;
                        result = keymap[row][col];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is just an example, the problem may be solved in some different way.
It's working (checked on the device). Contains simple debouncing mechanism.